# Custom Field Type inheritance PropertySchema

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a custom field type in SP2010 based on SPDateTime. I would like to inherit the fields in the UI under **Additional Column Settings** that exist as default for Date and Time.

Recreating the options in PropertySchema dosn't seem to be the right approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082936/sharepoint-2007-create-a-multi-line-text-custom-property-for-a-custom-field-type/5096480#5096480) in resolution, I'm afraid. There are many features that are hard-coded in for the default field types. These are mostly not inheritable, and often difficult to reproduce.